# Pine Script - How to get the UNIX time value of a variable

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have the following script that gets the previous month low, and plots a line at that value:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Low Lines", overlay=true)

pmonlow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', low[1])

lowLine = line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=pmonlow ,x2=bar_index, y2=pmonlow, extend=extend.right,
         color=color.red, width=2)
```

lowLine plots a line at the value of the previous monthly low, one bar back.

I'd like to place the start of the line on the date where the low actually occurred.

Is it possible to get the UNIX time value for the "pmonlow" variable so i could then use line.setxloc?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to get the chart's timeframe's timestamp of the low and not the higher timeframe's timestamp, we need to obtain the low when it occurs as it can't be retrieved using the security call. You would only be able to get the monthly open time via security.

```
new_month = change(time("M")) != 0

var float monthly_low = na
var int monthly_low_time = na

if new_month
    monthly_low := low
    monthly_low_time := time
else if low < monthly_low
    monthly_low := low
    monthly_low_time := time
    
var line monthly_low_line = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.red)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(monthly_low_line, x = monthly_low_time, y = monthly_low)
    line.set_xy2(monthly_low_line, x = time, y = monthly_low)
```